# Quick-launch in peoplesearchresult page

Tags: search, quick-launch, people-search

Can i make the quick launch available on peoplesearchresult page? on the search site collection?

Answer (score 0):

**1. Create a custom CSS file with the following text:**

```
<style type="text/css">
#s4-leftpanel {
  display:inherit!important;
  width:155px!important;
}
.s4-ca {
  margin-left:155px!important;
}
</style>
```

Save the file in "Style Library".

**2. Edit the peopleresults.aspx page.**

**3. Select "Add a Web Part" on the "Navigation Zone". Add a "Content Editor Web Part"**

**4. Edit the web part and set "Content Link" to the CSS file you created in step 1.**